# How to swap tensor axes efficiently in tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have to swap tensor's axes using `tf.transpose` to do the batch matrix multiplication (as the code shown below).

tensor input_a: shape [10000, 10000]

tensor input_b: shape [batch_size, 10000, 10]

tensor output:  shape [batch_size, 10000, 10]

```
# reshape_input_b: shape [10000, batch_size, 10]
transpose_input_b = tf.transpose(input_b, [1, 0, 2])

# transpose_input_b : shape [10000, batch_size * 10]
reshape_input_b = tf.reshape(transpose_input_b , [10000, -1])

# ret: shape [10000, batch_size * 10]
ret = tf.matmul(input_a, reshape_input_b, a_is_sparse = True)

# reshape_ret: [10000, batch_size, 10]
reshape_ret = tf.reshape(ret, [10000, -1, 10])

# output : [batch_size, 10000, 10]
output = tf.transpose(reshape_ret, [1, 0, 2])
```

However, it seems very slow. I noticed this in the document page of `tf.transpose`:

> In numpy transposes are memory-efficient constant time operations as they simply return a new view of the same data with adjusted strides.
>
> TensorFlow does not support strides, **so transpose returns a new tensor with the items permuted**.

So, I think it might be the reason why my code run slowly? Is there any way to swap tensor's axes, or do the batch matrix multiplication efficiently?

Comment: Why do you can do better than the `transpose` that `tensorflow` provides?  `numpy` transpose/swap is efficient because it only has to change the shape and strides, and doesn't need to copy data - that is until reshaping or other calculation requires contiguous data.

Comment: @hpaulj So, is there any way I can do the matrix multiplication like the code above, but without using `tf.transpose`? I need to multiply two matrix with different rank, transpose or axes swapping might be not necessary.

Comment: `np.einsum` can mix and match dimensions, but I don't know if tensorflow has this.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you, tensorflow has `tf.einsum`, I will try it.

Comment: @Ficush: Can you please confirm if using `tf.einsum` resolved your issue. Thanks!